# how to get default scrollbar to extjs grid without setting height in extjs

Tags: extjs6

I am facing an issue with extjs grid height. I want to display a grid with a scrollbar but it is not showing the scrollbar by default. If I set height for the grid then it is displaying but if I set the height manually it is not responsive in all systems based on the screen size grid is displaying.

I have taken one container with grid.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the layout attribute of the container to fit might solve this issue

```
layout: 'fit'
```

Comment: I have alrady given layout fit. but scrollbar is not coming

Comment: Can you share a code example to show how you've configured the container and the grid?